# asp.net gridview showheaderwhenempty works only in postback

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I realized that ShowHeaderWhenEmpty only works in PostBacks. Is there any way to make it work once the page is loaded?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"... ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true"... >
<EmptyDataTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="No records found"></asp:Label>
</EmptyDataTemplate>
```

When I have no info to show, the above message only appears in PostBacks, no when the page is loaded.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you are trying to do (specifically)?  It's kind of hard to tell what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Note: This answer assumes (based on your question) you are binding your* `GridView` *to a data source on PostBack, and not at all during* `Page_Load`.  *Please correct me if I'm wrong.*

The `<EmptyDataTemplate>` content only shows once your `GridView` has been databound.  If you are only databinding on Postback (based on some user interaction) one way to solve this problem would be to bind your `GridView` to an empty (artificial) dataset, just so the `<EmptyDataTemplate>` will show.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack
        Dim table As New DataTable
        GridView1.DataSource = table
        GridView1.DataBind()
    End If
End Sub
```

From the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatemplate.aspx) on the EmptyDataTemplate (emphasis mine):

> The empty data row is displayed in a `GridView` control when the **data
>   source that is bound to the control** does not contain any records.

If there is no datasource bound to the control, this property is not yet relevant.

Comment: @Somebody No problem at all =)